# CMake C++ Set Header DEBUG Variable on Compilation?

Tags: c++, cmake

is there a way to set a DEBUG variable on compilation?

Based on a Environment Variable or something like a target=release?

Comment: What is a "DEBUG variable?" Do you mean defining a preprocessor macro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) to Debug

e.g. `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug [...]` which will enable `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`.

And append custom flags like this such as enabling a debug macro only at debug build type :
`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DENABLE_DEBUG_MACRO")`

So this macro will be only enabled when`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.

Or as mentionned in the comment you could also just directly put `add_definitions(-DENABLE_DEBUG_MACRO)` if you do not care about the build type.

**Edit** to answer comment

> Currently I want to print something to the console in my program (not
>   cmake) if -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug is enabled

For that you can define in your C++ code a macro `DEBUG_PRINT` which will work only when `ENABLE_DEBUG_MACRO` is defined.

```
#ifdef ENABLE_DEBUG_MACRO
#  define DEBUG_PRINT(msg, ...) fprintf(stdout, "[debug] " msg "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#  define DEBUG_PRINT(msg, ...) 
#endif
```

[Live with debug mode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/965a83613f300977)

[Live without debug mode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02447ffecb54e553) (no debug message)

Comment: add_definitions(-DENABLE_DEBUG_MACRO)

Comment: @MarkJansen Yes we could do that but it would work for any build type.

Comment: This seems cool, however how could I use that inside my code?

Comment: @Christian Schmitt Could you explain a bit more your situation ? Do you need a demo ?

Comment: Currently I want to print something to the console in my program (not cmake) if -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug is enabled i already set that.

Comment: @coincoin: yes, just including additional options :)

Answer (score 0):

As @coincoin said, you can set the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to `debug`. If you want to set it as default to debug you can set the variable in the cmake file directly. But don't overwrite it when its already set, like this everyone else can use your cmake file like they are used to.

```
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
endif()
```

Comment: I do not set the build type by default. The user is free to set it or not in the command line.